# Django migrating foreign keys django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'asp052mysqlpy.#sql-6ac_56' (errno: 150)") error

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate a simple foreign key relation for a model in Django, but this results in a very strange and unsolvable error.

Error:

```sh
python manage.py migrate team
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: team
Running migrations:
  Applying team.0001_initial... OK
  Applying team.0002_auto_20191127_1643...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 255, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 252, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 378, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'asp052mysqlpy.#sql-6ac_56' (errno: 150)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 203, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py", line 216, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 523, in alter_field
    old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 744, in _alter_field
    self.execute(self._create_fk_sql(model, new_field, "_fk_%(to_table)s_%(to_column)s"))
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 133, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 255, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 252, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 378, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\teamwork\teamworkapp\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 280, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'asp052mysqlpy.#sql-6ac_56' (errno: 150)")
```

Models:

```py
class Tmteams(models.Model):
    teamid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tmteams'


class Tmteamsusers(models.Model):
    teamid = models.ForeignKey(Tmteams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='teamid')
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='userid')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tmteamsusers'
        unique_together = (('userid', 'teamid'),)
```

Migration file that errors:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('team', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='tmteamsusers',
            name='teamid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='teamid', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='team.Tmteams'),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='tmteamsusers',
            name='userid',
            field=models.ForeignKey(db_column='userid', on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='users.User'),
        ),
    ]
```

I'm using the following modules and MySQL version:
Django 2.1.5
mysqlclient 1.3.14
MySQl 5.1.7.3 Community edition

Anyone that can help me out?

Comment: All others migrations (including the required django admin migrations) have been succesfully run. This is the last migration that needs to be applied. I've manually executed all migrations in order, but the result when doing it automaically is the same. When I initiate the model with the foreign keys already there the error message is the same. I've serperated this from the original migration to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found and solved the problem. The table I'm referencing to (allmodusers) was still using the MyISAM database engine. I've changed the database engine of this table to InnoDB after reading the following article: https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/convert-myisam-to-innodb/.